# The name 'gs_ConnString' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
                }

        private void ClearForm()
        {
            tb_EmpNr.Clear();
            tb_LastName.Clear();
            tb_FirstName.Clear();
            tb_MiddleName.Clear();
            tb_Address.Clear();
            tb_Zip.Clear();
            tb_City.Clear();
            tb_State.Clear();
            tb_Phone.Clear();
            tb_PayLevel.Clear();
            tb_PayGrade.Clear();
            tb_DOH.Clear();
        }//end clear form

        private void GetCityState()
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "SELECT City, State " +
                                       " FROM tbl_Zip WHERE Zip=" + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + "";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Read();
                tb_City.Text = Reader.GetString(0);
                tb_State.Text = Reader.GetString(1);
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS GET ZIP ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end get city state

        private void GetRecFromDatabase(string s_EmpNr)
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "SELECT EmpNumber, EmpLastName, EmpFirstName, EmpMiddleName, EmpAddress, EmpZip," +
                                       " EmpPhone, EmpPayLevel, EmpPayGrade, EmpHireDate" +
                                       " FROM tbl_Employee WHERE EmpNumber=" + "\"" + s_EmpNr + "\"" + "";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Read();
                tb_EmpNr.Text = Reader.GetString(0);
                tb_LastName.Text = Reader.GetString(1);
                tb_FirstName.Text = Reader.GetString(2);
                tb_MiddleName.Text = Reader.GetString(3);
                tb_Address.Text = Reader.GetString(4);
                tb_Zip.Text = Reader.GetString(5);
                tb_Phone.Text = Reader.GetString(6);
                tb_PayGrade.Text = String.Format("{0}", Reader.GetInt32(7));
                tb_PayLevel.Text = String.Format("{0}", Reader.GetInt32(8));
                tb_DOH.Text = String.Format("{0:d}", Reader.GetDateTime(9));
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
                GetCityState();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS GET ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end GetRecFromDatabase




        private void b_Clear_Screen_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            ClearForm();
            tb_EmpNr.Focus();
        }

        private void b_Add_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Employee (EmpNumber, EmpLastName, EmpFirstName, EmpMiddleName, " +
                                                       "EmpAddress, EmpZip, EmpPhone, EmpHireDate, EmpPayLevel, EmpPayGrade)" +
                             "VALUES(" + "\"" + tb_EmpNr.Text + "\"" + ", "      //strings get double quotes
                                       + "\"" + tb_LastName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_FirstName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_MiddleName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Address.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Phone.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "#" + tb_DOH.Text + "#" + ", "
                                       + tb_PayLevel.Text + ", "
                                       + tb_PayGrade.Text
                                       + ")";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS ADD ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }

        private void b_Get_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get a specific rec
            GetRecFromDatabase(tb_EmpNr.Text);
        }

        private void tb_Zip_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get the city and state
            GetCityState();
        }

        private void b_Get_Next_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get next rec
            string s_NextRec = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(tb_EmpNr.Text) + 1);
            GetRecFromDatabase(s_NextRec);
        }

        private void b_Update_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//update the record
            try
            {
                string Query = "UPDATE tbl_Employee SET " +
                                    "EmpLastName =" + "\"" + tb_LastName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpFirstName =" + "\"" + tb_FirstName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpMiddleName =" + "\"" + tb_MiddleName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpAddress =" + "\"" + tb_Address.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpZip =" + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpPhone =" + "\"" + tb_Phone.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpHireDate =" + "#" + tb_DOH.Text + "#" + " " + ", " +
                                    "EmpPayLevel =" + Convert.ToInt32(tb_PayLevel.Text) + ", " +
                                    "EmpPayGrade =" + Convert.ToInt32(tb_PayGrade.Text) +
                               " WHERE EmpNumber =" + "\"" + tb_EmpNr.Text + "\"" + " ";

                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
                GetRecFromDatabase(tb_EmpNr.Text);
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                                "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end update click
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

The program is supposed to take data from a microsoft access database that I have saved in my debug folder of microsoft visual studio.  However, I am getting the error listed in the title of question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-This error appears four times throughout the code

Comment: Where is gs_connstring defined? or r u taking it from web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You never define `gs_ConnString`, as the error states. You could add it like so:

```
// using statements
// ...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string gs_ConnString = "[put the connection string here]";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I cant believe I forgot to add that in.  It builds the form now, however when I try to grab the data from the access database I get an error saying 'No value given for one or more required parameters'.  Any ideas? I added the Microsoft Access 14 as a reference in order to grab the data

Comment: You need to figure out what parameters you need, and set them in your connection string. I'm sorry, but I can't really help you with that.

Comment: I know the parameters are correct because I got them from my proff; however, I may have added the access file to the wrong folder? Is there a specific area that I need to add the file in order to access it?

Comment: Someone else would be better to answer your question now -- I know why your code has a compiler error, but I have no experience with Microsoft Access. I wish I could help you further, but I don't know how to help.